# Find the mode of multiple columns for each unique value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset with an ID column and 10 different regular services column and 1 premium service column.
A person could come in multiple times, so IDs can repeat. 
During a person's visit, they could also buy up to 10 regular services, plus that one premium service.

I want to be able to determine which regular service did each unique person buy the most of, and as which premium service did they buy the most of as well. If the modes of any service is the same for regular or premium, any will do.

Using pandas, my dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    Service1    Service2    Service3 .... Service10    Premium
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     A           B           C             Z            XX
1     B           C           D             Y            XY
1     A           B           C             O            XX
2     R           S           T             B            XX
```

I tried df.mode() and pd.Series.mode() but I keep getting errors. I'm trying to produce a list of unique clients (by ID), and the mode of all columns.

I also need a mode of a single column as well.

This is for the regular services (need to find the mode over 10 columns):

```
def servicemode(group):
    svcs_cols = [group['Service1'],
               group['Service2'],
               group['Service3'],
               group['Service4'],
               group['Service5'],
               group['Service6'],
               group['Service7'],
               group['Service8'],
               group['Service9'],
               group['Service10']]
    return pd.concat(dx_cols).dropna(inplace=False).agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])

df.groupby('ID').apply(servicemode)
```

This is for the premium service (need to find the mode in a single column):

```
df.groupby('ID')['Premium'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
```

This is the desired result:

```
ID    RegSvcMode    PremiumSvcMode
1     B             XX
2     R             XX
```

I prefer using pure pandas if possible -- any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why but it was working then stopped and keeps giving me this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your original code but here's one solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

>>>df
   Service1 Service2 Service3 Service10
ID
1         A        B        C         Z
1         B        C        D         Y
1         A        B        C         O
2         R        S        T         B

df_regsvc = df.groupby(df.index)['Service1','Service2','Service3','Service10'] \
    .apply(lambda x : list(chain.from_iterable([*x.values]))) \
    .apply(lambda x: max(x, key=x.count)).to_frame()

>>>df_regsvc
ID
1    B
2    R
dtype: object

# Join it with the aggregate for the Premium column
df_premium = df.groupby(df.index)['Premium'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]).to_frame()
df_agg = df_regsvc.join(df_premium)

>>>df_agg
    0 Premium
ID
1   B         XX
2   R         XX
```

Comment: It's weird, my original code for the regular services started to work again after an hour of poking at it. I still have no idea what I did to make it stop work, but I'm just glad as heck it's working now! As for the premium service column, I never managed to get that one to work. When I tried your code -- which was the same that I had already written (I've been using the .to_frame() to convert from series to join the dfs), I keep getting: IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: Is it possible the reason for the indexerror is because not all clients have a premium service? (It can be null) -- is there a way we can address that in the code?

Comment: It seems like I am correct that the NaN values are throwing the index off -- when I replaced all NaN with a placeholder value, the code worked, but because that placeholder value was the most common, that became the mode. I'm hoping there's a way to identify any modes that are NOT the placeholder value, if that makes sense!

Comment: Figured it out -- instead of replacing NaN I just drop them, since they are not necessary for the remainder of the frequency count! Since your answer was helpful in at least assuring me that I wasn't going crazy with my code (and thus is technically correct in answering my problem), I'm giving you due credit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Art Thanks for the credit :) You are also correct regarding the NaNs. With the original method of `df.groupby('ID')['Premium'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])`, you get the index error when the grouping results in an empty series. Instead of using `agg()`, you can also use `apply()`, which returns an empty series instead of an error `df.groupby(df.index)['Premium'].apply(pd.Series.mode)`