# Generate a new pandas Dataframe composed of the Unique userIDs and the mode in the other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So my dataframe looks like this.

```
userID.   A.   B.   C
  1.      X.   O.   1   
  2.      X.   N.   2
  1.      X.   O.   3
  1.      Y.   O.   4
```

Each unique User ID's could occur any number of times. What I'm trying to do is to generate a new Pandas Dataframe where each row contains a unique ID for userID, and the values for columns A,B,C are the mode for each of those unique users. If mode is tied for any column, any of those tied values is fine. For example below is what I'm looking for.

```
userID.   A.   B.   C
  1.      X.   O.   1
  2.      X.   N.   2
```

I saw a similar post here ([Find the mode of multiple columns for each unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409848/find-the-mode-of-multiple-columns-for-each-unique-value))  But this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

More complex Example

```
UserID.       A.   B.   C
      1.      Y.   O.   1   
      2.      X.   N.   2
      1.      X.   O.   3
      1.      Y.   O.   4
      1.      X.   O.   1   
      2.      X.   N.   2
      1.      X.   O.   3
      1.      Y.   O.   4
      1.      X.   O.   1   
      2.      X.   N.   2
      1.      X.   O.   3
      1.      Y.   O.   4
```

Will give the same result:

```
userID.   A.   B.   C
  1.      X.   O.   1
  2.      X.   N.   2
```

EDIT: Note that I used X,0, 1 for values. In reality the values could be str, float, ints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy.mode` and then `dropna`:

```
df = df.groupby('userID.').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 1:].mode()).dropna()

           A.  B.  C
userID.             
1       0  X.  O.  1
2       0  X.  N.  2
```

To fix your index, use `reset_index`:

```
df = (
    df.groupby('userID.').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 1:].mode())
      .dropna().reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
)

   userID.  A.  B.  C
0        1  X.  O.  1
1        2  X.  N.  2
```

Or more concise as [`piRSquared`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147757/generate-a-new-pandas-dataframe-composed-of-the-unique-userids-and-the-mode-in-t/59147835#comment104521471_59147835) mentioned:

```
df = df.groupby('userID.', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0])

   userID.  A.  B.  C
0        1  X.  O.  1
1        2  X.  N.  2
```

Comment: `df.groupby('UserID.', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0])`

Comment: What is the purpose of the x.iloc[:, 1:]

Comment: To prevent getting the mode of the column `userID` as well. `iloc[:, 1:]` means: "get all the rows and all columns FROM the second one" @QwertyQwerts

Comment: Ah thank you. It seems like I get a IndexError: index out of bounds error. As a side note, I'm getting this as a warning UserWarning: Unable to sort modes: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
  warn("Unable to sort modes: {error}".format(error=e))

Comment: Seems like your example dataframe is not a good representation of your actual data, since I tried my solution on both dataframes and I got correct output. `iloc` is causing the problem in this case I think. Try the solution on the bottom of `piRSquared` @QwertyQwerts

Comment: I'm getting an index out of bounds error still. Interesting enough, the amount of UserWarnings have reduced to a single one. Could it be that since I have multiple IDs, such as user ID, customer ID, middleman ID, which are represeneted with various nonalphanumeric strings.... pandas is crashing trying to parse it?